# How do I know what errors are being thrown in my try-catch blocks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012, try-catch

When I'm building my programs, I have a number of try-catch blocks and when they throw errors, I seem to have trouble seeing what caused the error -  I've tried looking at the stack-trace but I always end up commenting out the error handling and re-running.

Is there a better way? (I'm sure there must be ...)

If every time I have to comment out the bits of my try-catch to figure out **why** it was throwing it seems like I should be able to look at the stack-trace or something.  Sorry if it's a simple question but it should have a simple answer ...

Comment: Not sure why it was a bad question but I apologise none-the-less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, do the follow steps:

- Menu [Debug]
- Option [Exceptions...]
- On the right of [Common Language Runtime Exceptions], check the box under [Thrown].

Now your application will always stop (as if it is a breakpoint) at the line where an exception is thrown.

Comment: Ahh, thanks ... that's perfect.  Does exactly what I thought VS was supposed to do.  Don't happen to know why I was down voted so rigorously do you?

Comment: Well... I think you are downvoted for simply not knowing how to read a stacktrace. I must agree: you must be able to. But this tric is just working much better. So... Do not worry about. Sometimes my answers, correct and all, are downvoted too.

Comment: Thanks - It's tough on here trying to ask good questions- especially when you are learning.  Sometimes you just don't search for the right things ...

Comment: @Sisyphus: That is correct. Just do not loose your hope and just keep learning and asking questions! :)